# image doesnt shows on JLabel when click on next button, using java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I am trying to make small program that shows pic on JLabel when user click on Next Button.The Problem is when i click on next button it shows nothing.but if i resize frame it shows all pics from directory. instead of one picture at a time.
Please excuse my English.
here is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        frame f = new frame();
        f.gui();
        f.actions();
    }
}

class frame {

    BufferedImage file;
    File img;
    ImageIcon icon;

    JLabel image;
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    String[] path = { "juice.jpg", "gal.jpg", "truck.jpg", "Drive.jpg" };

    JButton next = new JButton("NEXT");
    JButton pre = new JButton("PREVOIUS");
    JTextField field = new JTextField(10);

    static int num = 0;

    public void gui() {

        frame = new JFrame("pic gallery");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
        frame.setLayout(flow);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        panel.add(next);
        panel.add(pre);
        panel.add(field);

        JLabel piclabel = new JLabel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

    void actions() {

        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                img = new File(path[num]);
                System.out.println(num);
                try {
                    file = ImageIO.read(img);
                    icon = new ImageIcon(file);
                    image = new JLabel("", icon, JLabel.CENTER);

                    image.setVisible(true);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(image);

                } catch (IOException g) {

                }
                if (num < path.length - 1) {
                    num++;
                    field.setText(num + "");

                } else {
                    num = 0;

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/651201/GUI/java/Image-doesnt-shows-propely-java. Quit cross posting!!! Its annoying to spend the time answering a question only to find out the exact same answer has already been given and you didn't bother to reply stating an answer has been found.

Comment: yes i posted there but i didn't get answer .even since now nobody replied on that. then whats wrong in ask questions in another forum .

Comment: `but i didn't get answer` - yes you did. I answered. `whats wrong in ask questions in another forum` - did you even read my comment??? You didn't bother responding in the other forum that you got an answer, so I wasted my time helping you out when I could have spent the time helping other people who did not have an answer to a question. That's what the problem is when you post on two forums. You never bother to reply to the other forum stating you have the answer.

Comment: yeah  i just checked there u replied.Thanks

Comment: Don't thank me here. Thank me there. Reply stating that the answer  did solve the problem so others reading the question can learn from the answer. Or make a comment saying you got a solution in the other forum? Its possible somebody else might read the question and think you are still looking for an answer and waster their time trying to provide another anwer. Be considerate of people who volunteer time to answer questions. When you ask a question follow up everywhere you ask the question!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `frame.revalidate()` and `frame.repaint()` after `frame.getContentPane().add(image);`

Swing is lazy when it comes to performing updates to the layout hierarchy, which is good thing, imagine adding a few dozen components and having the entire component hierarchy been updated for each one.

So, instead, you need to update the container manually when you've made changes

> added as you suggested . now it shows next image on frame along with prevous image. but i wants 1 image at a time

Then remove the first image, or better yet, instead of creating a new `JLabel` each time, create a single `JLabel` and simply change it's `icon` property, which should invalidate the container automatically

Comment: Please, someone kindly point out the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Or use the SwingUtilities SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Component); method

Comment: @jordandap Oh please, dear god, no, never, that suggestion could only be worse if you suggested using `updateUI`, these methods have NOTHING to do with revalidating the component layout but have to do with revalidating the look and feel delegates settings, which is horrendously inefficient.  `revalidate` is selective in it's update process, looking for containers which have been previously been marked as invalidate and skipping those which have not changed and would not be affected by the changes been made. `invaidate`, `validate` (and simply) `revalidate` are the better choices

Comment: i added as you suggested . now it shows next image on frame  along with previous image. but i wants 1 image at a time

Comment: @PreetSingh Then remove the first image, or better yet, instead of creating a new `JLabel` each time, create a single `JLabel` and simply change it's icon property, which should invalidate the container automatically

Answer (score 0):

In your ActionListener for next you need to remove the previous Label then add the new Label

```
try
{
     file = ImageIO.read(img);
     icon = new ImageIcon(file);
     if(image != null) frame.remove(image);
     image = new JLabel("", icon, SwingConstants.CENTER);

     image.setVisible(true);
     frame.getContentPane().add(image);
     frame.revalidate();
     frame.repaint();
}
catch (IOException g)
{
}
```

Comment: Wow, really, like what I said 8 minutes ago, would never have guessed

Comment: @MadProgrammer wow really? It was 5 minutes ago and about 30 seconds before I posted this. I hadn't even seen your edit before I posted this

Comment: *"and about 30 seconds before I posted this"* - So why add nothing new and simply repeat what has already been said?

Comment: You posted 13 minutes ago but edited 5 minutes ago. and 5 minutes ago you added the same as what I said. And I had not seen your edit before I posted.

Comment: Actually, the original post read *"Add frame.revalidate() and frame.repaint() after frame.getContentPane().add(image);"* - Feel free to check the history of the question if you don't believe me

Comment: I was answering the part "Only show 1 image at once"  if(image != null) frame.remove(image);

Comment: Could you make small edit (maybe format the code) so I can lift the downvote...still not happy though